# How to debug *.ts files of ionic 2 project in chrome inspect devices?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I've built my ionic 2 application in android using ionic build android.
App is working fine.
I'm using Chrome inspect devices to debug android app.
Now, i want to debug my login.ts(which is component file).
However i can't see my Login.ts file in files list(Please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlzHg.png) image for reference). Why it is not showing any files from project src folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this to your package.json:

`"config": {
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_source_map_type": "#inline-source-map"
  }`

Do a rerun (`ionic run android`) and open dev tools (search for Chrome Remote Debugging). There's a flash of resources getting reloaded in the sources tab. You should be able to see your entire project structure under android_assets.

Works for ios with Safari debugging too.

Answer (score -2):

So ionic when compiled transfers everything to JavaScript. To debug you should use console.log statements in your code and check the console to debug based on the console.logs

Comment: Isn't it unfair to put so many console.log() statement in every part which needs to be debug? Also i have to build application everytime to see results, it will take too much time. There should be another solution for this.

Comment: @NiravParsana how would that be unfair? Once you resolve the problem you can comment them out. Other than that I don't know how else you would debug if there is no output of where the data flow is on the page.

Comment: "how else you would debug", that's what i'm finding for, pal :)

Comment: Can I ask why you don't wanna use console.log ?

Comment: Actually i want to debug hardware back button event, also i want to observe some variables and all other things, isn't it takes too much console.log() line? Instead if i can debug my component files, it would be too easier for me, because it saves time a lot too.

Comment: Hey i got my all functions in main.js file. I got breakpoint too.
Now the issue is below.

`backButtonAction() {
    this.gotoOrders();
  }`

whenever i click hardware back button, i got break point in this function but it can't find gotoOrders() function which is already i have as below:

`gotoOrders(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/Orders']);
  }`